# Removing Characters From String In Php

Tags: php, string, substring, trim

**File Name**

```
cars-lights-neon-1920x1080.jpg
cars-lights-neon-3840x2160.jpg
cars-lights-neon-800x600.jpg
```

What I Need is

```
cars-lights-neon.jpg
```

What I Tried

```
$name="cars-lights-neon-1920x1080.jpg";
$newname =   substr($name, 0, -4); //removing.jpg
// Real name
$rev= strrev("$newname"); // outputs "0801x0291-noen-sthgil-srac"
$revok= strstr($rev, '-'); //outputs "-noen-sthgil-srac"
$neutral = strrev("$revok"); //outputs "cars-lights-neon-"
$neutral = substr($neutral, 0, -1); //outputs "cars-lights-neon"

$filename = $neutral.".jpg"; //outputs "cars-lights-neon.jpg";
```

This Code Also Works fine.. But it can be done in Simple steps..So What i am Asking is for better code..

//File Name and Resolution is coming from database so it is not same every time..
Thnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`preg_replace`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) function of PHP like as

```
$name = "cars-lights-neon-1920x1080.jpg";
echo preg_replace('/(-\d+x\d+)/','',$name);//cars-lights-neon.jpg
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/470971)

Comment: One Thing More
cars-lights-neon-3840x2160.jpg
I Also Need Width and Height<br>
$width = "3840";
$height ="2160";

Comment: Simply use `preg_match('/-(\d+)x(\d+)/',$name,$m); print_r($m);` [Check This](https://eval.in/470993)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$string = 'cars-lights-neon-1920x1080.jpg';
$filename = preg_replace('/-[0-9]{3,4}x[0-9]{3,4}/', '', $string);
```